# Xamarin Forms iOS - Runtime does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin Forms project, following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/) tutorial on creating a custom map. I am receiving an error:

`The name "Runtime" does not exist in the current context`

To my knowledge `Runtime` is a part of the `System` library as explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Runtime/), and I am `using System` in my code so I am unsure why I am seeing this error. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime;
using CoreGraphics;
using CoreLocation;
using CustomRenderer;
using CustomRenderer.iOS;
using MapKit;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Google.Maps;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        MKPolygonRenderer polygonRenderer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                if (nativeMap != null)
                {
                    nativeMap.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
                    nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = null;
                    polygonRenderer = null;
                }
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;

                nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;

                CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[formsMap.ShapeCoordinates.Count];

                int index = 0;
                foreach (var position in formsMap.ShapeCoordinates)
                {
                    coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                    index++;
                }

                var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
                nativeMap.AddOverlay(blockOverlay);
            }
        }

        MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
        {
            if (polygonRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
            {
                var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
                polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon)
                {
                    FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                    StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                    Alpha = 0.4f,
                    LineWidth = 9
                };
            }
            return polygonRenderer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetNSObject` exists in the `ObjCRuntime` namespace:

```
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(....
```

Re: [MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject/p/System.IntPtr/)